# Error in Procedure with in clause using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dataset, call, vb.net-2010

Using mysql to write procedure. but am getting error when i call this procedure in mysql.
am not geeting the correct result in dataset.i want to pass all these phone  numbers in single argument.

```
my procedure
------------
CREATE  PROCEDURE pro_dndtesting1(in p text)
begin
  select fld_phonenumber from tbl_dndno_1 where fld_phonenumber in (p) and fld_opstype='A';
end
$$


 am getting error when i call this procedure in mysql

 calling statement
 -----------------
  call pro_dndtesting1("9942321400","9490582992","9490597318","9494363015","9703210545","9494304399","8790989211","9133733635","8706744769","8197401062","7382936474","9949290637","994961722")


error 
------
 Error Code: 1318. Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE smsdnd.pro_dndtesting1; expected 1, got 2614


my aspx.vb code
----------------
  For i = 0 To Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim dq As String = ""

                    excelphone = Ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + """" & excelphone & """" & ","


                Next
                Dim n As Integer
                n = TextBox2.Text.Length

                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0, TextBox2.Text.Length - 1)
                Dim dnd As New DataSet1TableAdapters.pro_dndtesting1TableAdapter
                Dim dnddt As DataSet1.pro_dndtesting1DataTable = dnd.GetData(TextBox2.Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly - you should use comma-separated text, e.g. - '1112233,1115555,2223333'.
- Secondly - use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to filter records in table.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_dndtesting1(IN p VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SELECT
    fld_phonenumber
  FROM
    tbl_dndno_1
  WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(fld_phonenumber, p);
END
```

Run procedure:

```
CALL pro_dndtesting1('1112233,1115555,2223333');
```

Comment: am getting error like Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'procedure pro_dndtesting2

Comment: am calling that procedure like call procedure pro_dndtesting2('9010905107,8897532875,9840907301');

Comment: is it possible to pass 6000 to 7000 comma separated text in the variable p

Comment: Remove 'procedure' keyword after CALL statement; call procedure pro_dndtesting2('9010905107,8897532875,9840907301') -> call pro_dndtesting2('9010905107,8897532875,9840907301').

Comment: ya i do it now thanks. but if i pass 6000 to 7000 comma separated text value to the variable p means

Comment: When `p` is VARCHAR, then the maximum length is 65535 chars (in my example length is 255); BLOB data types may contain more information. Alternative variant is to populate additional (temporary) table with phone numbers, and JOIN it with your table.

Comment: i change the datatype as blob in mysql procedure. but am getting erron in aspx.vb.

Comment: Try to use text BLOB types as TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT. Try to call this procedure in MySQL client, it should work with text types.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `p` is not an array. The [`in` clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) expects an array, and you are providing a `string`. Hence, the error.

Now, to resolve the issue, I guess you can't pass an array to a mysql stored procedure, so you might want to build the array in the proc itself using for loop and parsing the `p` string, and eventually pass it to the query.

Hope this helps.

#### EDIT

I see, you are passing a lot of parameters, but your proc is just taking the 1st parameter as input. This is also wrong, and is the main error here. The above clarification hold good, if the `p` parameter would have input as

```
p="9942321400--9490582992--9490597318--9494363015--9703210545--9494304399--8790989211--9133733635--8706744769--8197401062--7382936474--9949290637--994961722"
```

then, you could just go with solution as stated above.

Comment: can u help how to change the mysql procedure. am new to mysql